# SCCM 1606 & ADK 1607

Tags: sccm, system-administration, adk, winpe, ccm

So l’m kind new to SCCM’s OSD and I’ve been assigned to do an upgrade for Windows 7 workstation to Windows 10 v1703.

I read online that the maximum ADK supported by SCCM 1606 is v1607, lucky I also read some posts online saying that it worked fine with Windows 10 v1706 although Microsoft does not support it.

Now, my questions is our environment has an older ADK version that I don’t wish to remove if that possible. Can I just  install the new ADK + upload new images to console + use new USMT Package for user data migration? Or must I upgrade the whole winPE to the new ADK environment? And if so, is there is any easier way then using scripts to update image and adk level ? ( older SCCM versions don’t have the option of reloading boot images)

If anyone can guide me please, I’m supposed to start the upgrade as soon as possible as windows 7 is going to be out of support in 2020.

Answer (score 0):

The old ADK has to be removed then we could install the latest ADK. Otherwise, we would see the following error message.

[image]

Manually updating the boot image in the SCCM, we need to copy the latest wim file to the location used in the SCCM and run a script to update it. Refer to the following link to get the detailed steps.

https://www.scconfigmgr.com/2014/02/28/default-boot-images-was-not-updated-after-a-configmgr-2012-r2-upgrade/

Best Regards,
Ray